# Google maps geocoder too much recursion using ajax

Tags: google-maps, jquery, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am using google maps geocoder which uses an asynchronous to return the lat and lng values. It works perfect. I then want to pass those lat lng values to an ajax call to my database to search against. I can't figure out though how to know when the asynchronous part is done to then run the ajax portion.

lat and lng are always empty when this runs.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
function getLatLng(address, fn){
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
     fn(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng()); 
  });
}

getLatLng(address, function(lat,lng){

        var formData = $('#form').serialize();      

        if (lat!='' && lng!='') {
              $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/_templates/map_ajax",
              dataType:'json',
              data: formData,
              error: function() {
                $('#status').text('Update failed. Try again.').slideDown('slow');
              },
              success: function(formData) {                                                               
                buildMarkers(formData);             
              }                                   
             });        //ajax close    
        }

}); // close getLatLng
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, the only thing wrong with your code is that you never post the lat/lng values to your AJAX service, you're only sending the serialized form data.  I simplified your example to something like:

```
function getLatLng(address, fn){
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
   fn(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());
  });
}

getLatLng("new york", function(lat,lng){
  if (lat!='' && lng!='') {
  console.log(lat);
  console.log(lng);
  }
});
```